# RSS to obtain new questions on-the-fly?

Tags: support, rss

I was wondering whether there's an RSS or XML way of getting new answers periodically from english.SE

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it > https://english.stackexchange.com/feeds

Comment: Could this perhaps be included in the markup of the front page? At least Firefox is not able to detect a feed on http://english.stackexchange.com/questions. Alternative feeds, like those only for favorite tags, would also be nice.